# how to Destroy all sessions at one Time in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want destroy all sessions at one time. I have tried `Session.Abondon()` method but I don't know why this is not destroying all the sessions.

Comment: Must clear out this: Clear The current user session data, or ALL session data from all users ? - because answers are splited on this two cases.

Comment: @Aristos, `Session.Clear` only clears the current session - see my answer.

Comment: Session.Abondon() can clear all the session of that particular user who is requesting, NOT ALL APPLICATION USERS SESSION.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't destroy all the sessions, you can only clear current session. You *probably* have to recycle the application pool to clear out all sessions.

---

Use `HttpSessionState.Clear` to clear out current session

[From MSDN - HttpSessionState.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Removes all keys and values from the session-state collection.

Call it like :

```
Session.Clear();
```

Answer (score 5):

> I want destroy all sessions at one time

I'm fairly sure you can't do this, short of recycling the application.

The currently accepted answer suggests using `Session.Clear`, but this only clears the current session - it is the same as `Session.RemoveAll`.

Why are there two methods `Clear` and `RemoveAll` that do exactly the same thing?  I suspect `RemoveAll` is provided for backwards compatibility with the [ASP Classic Session object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319(v=vs.90).aspx), while `Clear` is the more usual method name for clearing items from a .NET Collection.

Comment: do you know if there is still no way to access all sessions from the server?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are three methods that can remove session
variables

```
Session.Clear()
Session.RemoveAll()
Session.Abandon()
```

`Clear()` and `RemoveAll()` perform the same thing: remove the session variables
but keep the current session in memory. Whereas, `Abandon()` ends the current
session.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Session.Contents.RemoveAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Session.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear.aspx) or [Session.RemoveAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.removeall%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Method

```
Session.Clear()
    or
 Session.RemoveAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
this.Page.Session.Clear();
```

Abandon is for the current session only.