# Session variable clearing methods will clear current browser sessions only?

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, session-variables, session-state

Following session variables clearing methods are used in log out click

```
Session.Clear(); 
Session.RemoveAll();
Session.Abandon();
```

If i open my website in two browsers and log out from one browser.The session variables are not clearing in the second browser.So it is not redirecting to log out.

The above mentioned methods will clear only the current browser session variables only? what is the efficient way to remove all the browser sessions??

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172284/795683

Answer (score 2):

In general, when two browsers connect to your website, there are two different sessions will be instantiated. The information in each session is independent from all other ones. So when you remove/clear the session, only the current session will be affected.

To destroy all sessions, suppose that you are using InProc mode for session state (there are other modes => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx), you can destroy all sessions by restarting the Application Pool. There are [some examples on MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
        ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
        ApplicationPoolCollection applicationPoolCollection = serverManager.ApplicationPools;
        foreach (ApplicationPool applicationPool in applicationPoolCollection)
        {
            //...
            applicationPool.Recycle();
            //...
        }
        // CommitChanges to persist the changes to the ApplicationHost.config.
        serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

P/s: The ServerManager class resides in [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration) package. This behavior shouldn't be implemented in log out event.

There are options to restart the app pools also

- Modify web.config file
- Upgrade a new .dll file
- Use IIS manager

Comment: Is it a good practice to restart the application pool in log out event. Can you tell the disadvantages of the same??

Comment: No, we should never do that in log out event. It's wrong if doing this. The code is just for information when we really need to do that (often when there was an issue such as data cache, memory leak...).

Comment: then what is the best way to clear sessions from all browser.That can be done in logout event?

Comment: "That can be done in logout event?", I don't think so. I haven't seen we need this logic in an application code. Use IIS Manager or modify web.config is convenient.

Comment: @hazjack: whether i need to use the code u have mentioned above in my logout click?

Comment: @neeta no, logout should only clear current session & return a default page. it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using master page then inside not page postback use this code

```html
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
                if (Session["ObjUser"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/UI/Login.aspx", true);
                }
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/UI/Login.aspx", true);
                }
```

so here session objuser is ur current user session..
if not using master page then direct put this code in ur login not is postback.
this i have checked working fine with two browsers.