# How to clear ALL active sessions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

1) I'd like to know how can I clear all sessions in asp.net so every user logged to a system can't work unless they log-in again.

2) Is there any way to iterate through all sessions to make an exception for admin users stored in session?

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172268/how-to-destroy-all-sessions-at-one-time-in-asp-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Destroy all sessions at one Time in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172268/how-to-destroy-all-sessions-at-one-time-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Session state from within another session however you can share data via the Application state and use that to kill other sessions when they next do a request via Global.asax

Keep track of time when each session was started via `Session_Start` in Global.asax

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    Session["dtmStart"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Abandon each session when it next requests via `Application_AcquireRequestState` in Global.asax if the session was started before the current kill time stored in Application state

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Occurs as the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET responds to a request.

    // Check if session should be killed
    if (Application["dtmClearSessions"] != null 
        && Session["dtmStart"] != null
        && (DateTime)Application["dtmClearSessions"] > (DateTime)Session["dtmStart"])
    {
        // Check if user is an administator
        if (Application["lstAdminUserIds"] != null && Session["intMyUserId"] != null)
        {
            List<int> lstAdminUserIds = (List<int>)Application["lstAdminUserIds"];
            int intMyUserId = (int)Session["intMyUserId"];
            if (lstAdminUserIds.Contains(intMyUserId))
                return;
        }

        Session.Abandon();
    }
}
```

To flag that the sessions should be abandoned simply set `Application["dtmClearSessions"] = DateTime.Now;` for example via a button press on a page.

```
protected void btnKillEmAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Application["dtmClearSessions"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException ex) { throw ex; }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: RecordError(ex, "my_page.btnKillEmAll_Click", Request);
        // TODO: show error on screen litError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```